# store mutiple values in php session

Tags: php, session

I am writing a script in php, which is quite similar to a shopping cart. what i want to do is when a users adds a certain product i need to add the productid to a session variable,without storing in a database. so each time the user adds a product the productid needs to be stored in a session variable.

and when the user checkouts i need to retrieve all the productids and display?

can some one please explain me how to do it? coz im fine with 1 product but not sure how to store and retrieve multiple values.

any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place an [Array](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in the [Session](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Add the items to the array.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $apples;
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $oranges;
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $pears;
```

*Note: replace `$apples`, `$oranges` and `$pears` with your product ids.*

You access the array like any other array in PHP, e.g. to [count](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the items:

```
echo count($_SESSION['cart']);
```

and to [iterate](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) over the items:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

You could also wrap the Session into an object and provide access to the cart through a method interface, but I leave that for someone else to explain.

Comment: Then you can use `count($_SESSION['cart'])` to count how many items in your cart.  Use `foreach` on `$_SESSION['cart']` to loop through each item to display

Comment: it's probably worth saving the session to a database and then if the customer leaves the site before completions or times out you can retrieve the cart from the db and set it back as a session.

Comment: $_SESSION['cart'] = array(); is not needed.

Comment: @user267351 True. I'll leave it for verbosity, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: While $_SESSION['cart']=array() is not strictly required, it is generally good practice to declare variables before using them.

Answer (score 3):

Each session is an associative array. You can store other arrays in it, like

```
$_SESSION['products']=array();
$_SESSION['products'][]='123123'
$_SESSION['products'][]='cow_34526'
```

and then you can work with this as with any other array, i.e.

```
foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $item){
  //display or process as you wish
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the following in a file called `index.php` and give it a test:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['product'])) {
    $products = isset($_SESSION['products']) ? $_SESSION['products'] : array();
    $products[] = $_POST['product'];
    $_SESSION['products'] = $products;
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>
        <form name="input" action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="product" />
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$role=json_encode($checkUser1[0]);
$role2=str_replace('"','',$role);
$company=json_encode($checkUser2[0]);
$company=str_replace('"','',$company);
$_SESSION['LOGIN_STATUS']=true;
$_SESSION['UNAME']=$uname;
$_SESSION['datefrmt']='dd/mm/yy';
$_SESSION['role']=$role2;
$_SESSION['company']=$company;
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.