# Store mutiple values in Session PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session

** UPDATE **
The code is working now. But Now I would like to have a `div` display the sessions saved. This div is on the same page as the items and is called `items` I tried using a refresh script. But this doesn't work.

Is this posible via jQuery or should I use AJAX (I'm not really "into" Ajax yet)...

Owke, lets see if I can explain this the best I can... I'm using Wordpress for a site I'm making now I would like to store the "liked" items a custom clicks.

So what I did was open a session in my header

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

Then on the page that needs to store the "like" I have the following code:

```
<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["item"] = get_the_title();
?>
```

And where I would like to `echo` it I placed this code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['item'])){
    echo $_SESSION['item'];
    };
?>
```

This all works like it should, BUT there are multiple items a custom could like on one page. AND I would like to store all of them in my session. But it only stores 1 session at a time.

Do I need to work with numbers of prefixes, like item-x and item-y?

I found this bit of code: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223870/4367486)

But because I'm using Wordpress and I just want the title I cant replace $apples, $oranges and $pears with your product ids. Because for me its just

`<?php the_title(); ?>`

So this, for me, won't work:

```
<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["boot"] = array(); 
    $_SESSION["boot"][] = the_title();
?>
```

Every time... how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `item` session every time. You need to make this an array.

```
$_SESSION["item"][] = get_the_title();
```

Now to `echo` them, you want to get rid of duplicates, so use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['item'])){
    echo implode("<br />", array_unique($_SESSION['item']));
}
```

**POC:** https://repl.it/Cd7l

Comment: Thanks for the code! It works like a charm! The only thing is... It shows all the Items and not the one I marked as "like".

Comment: Do I need to destroy the session first? Using `<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset();

// destroy the session
session_destroy();

?>`

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate slightly on what was just said: `$_SESSION[]` is an array which, like any other PHP array, stores arbitrary values under one or more "keys," such as `"item"`.

Like any other PHP array, each value can be a single *scalar,* such as a book-title *string* or a single *number,* **or** it can be, itself, an array. (This is similar in concept to "a two-dimensional array.")  Each of *those* array-keys could, in turn, lead to any other sort of information you wish to store:  PHP data-structures can be arbitrarily deep, and PHP will store it all in your "session."

Now, if it were *me,* I would probably eliminate duplicates when I stored the values, so that I could be sure that the stored session information didn't contain duplicates at all.  Thus, I wouldn't have to do anything special when I `echo`ed them. Something like this:

```
$_SESSION["item"] = array_unique($_SESSION["item"]);
```

... *exactly* as I might do with any other PHP array.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration!