# Storing Form Data as a Session Variable on Multiple Pages

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I just wondering if its possible to store form data as Session on Multiple Pages?

I have 5 Pages on my Site, every page has an form with an input field on it.
I want save all Sessions and input values on all 5 Pages, and `echo` it on the last page.

I had saved the `session_start();` in one file and include it on every page:

**session_start.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
```

On the top of page before `<!DOCTYPE html>` i add it like this on every page:

**Page 1:**

```
<?php

    include("config.php");
    require_once("session_start.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

 } 

?>
```

then in the Body:

```
<form action="" method"post">
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

**Page 2:**

```
<?php

        include("config.php");
        require_once("session_start.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
     $_SESSION['passwort'] = $_POST['passwort'];

     } 

    ?>

then in the Body again:

    <form action="" method"post">
    <input type="text" name="passwort"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
    </form>
```

I can echo the `email Session` on the Page 2 without Problems with:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["email"];
 ?>
```

But get an error on the page `Undefined index: passwort` if i do it on the same way as in Page 1.

And continue on the other 3 Pages, whats wrong with my Way?
With my code here i can save the Session only from the Page before and `echo` it on the next page.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [store mutiple values in php session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223846/store-mutiple-values-in-php-session)

Comment: If you are storing in SESSION, then extract the stored data via `$_SESSION['email']` and `$_SESSION['passwort']`;

Comment: Hm dont understand it.. What you mean with `$_SESSION['passwort']`

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['passwort']`

Comment: Yes and how can i `echo` it on page 5? With this i can `echo` it only on the next page from the form before..

Answer (score 2):

So long as you are successfully calling `session_start();` at the start of each new page load, you will be carrying the previously store session data forward.

Yes, you will need to transfer the form-submission data from `$_POST` to the `$_SESSION` array each time.

After this snippet on page 1:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { 
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}
```

Your session will contain:

```
$_SESSION = ["email" => "example@email.com"];
```

Then after this snippet on page 2:

```
if (isset($_POST['passwort'])) { 
    $_SESSION['passwort'] = $_POST['passwort'];
}
```

Your session will contain:

```
$_SESSION = [
    'email' => 'example@email.com',
    'passwort' => 'p@$$w()rt'
];
```

And so on, for the pages to follow.

When you want to check what is in your array, you can simply call `var_export($_SESSION)`.

When you want to access particular elements, use their key.

E.g. `echo $_SESSION['passwort'];`